# CKEditor "Permission denied" error inside IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) v4.5.6 (along with Angular 1.2.0 and jQuery 1.11.3) in my app which has to be IE8 compatibile. 
Other browsers are not throwing any errors but when I load page with editor inside IE8 it throws "Permission denied" error inside line 54 of ckeditor.js file:

```
getDocument:function(){return new CKEDITOR.dom.document(this.$.ownerDocument||
this.$.parentNode.ownerDocument)}
```

Also, I was unable to open [cdn link](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard-all/ckeditor.js) inside IE8, I get error:
[image]

Code used inside ckEditor directive is rather simple - couple of config setters, replace method for toolbar and then getData() and setData() on model update, something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = false;
var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0],
    {
        toolbar: [
            {name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']}
        ]
    });

ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
    if(ngModel.$viewValue){
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
    }
});

function updateModel() {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
    });
}

ck.on('change', updateModel);
```

Inside html file:

```
 <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>

 <textarea class="textarea form-control" ng-if="!loading"
    data-ck-editor="" ng-model="test.editorContent"> </textarea>
```

Although editor is loaded and data is correctly diplayed, this error is iritating. Any help?

Comment: I'd probably start by using the latest version of CKEditor as this one is a bit old.

Comment: @DavidG, ver 4.5.6 is not that old

Comment: @Dekel That's why I said it's a *bit* old , or did you not read my comment?

Comment: @NikolaB, are you able to provide an example? It sounds like a CORS problem. Ver 4 of CKEditor is not fully compatible with IE8, however it should work.

Comment: @Dekel Also let's face it, anything from 8 months ago is most certainly old.

Comment: @DavidG, with that I agree, however nothing in the latest versions is related to IE8 bug fixes :)

Comment: @Dekel No, but it should be the first step in debugging an external library just making sure you are up to date is important. Also who is to say the fix was included in the release notes.

Comment: @Dekel, I updated question and provided code sample with use of ckEditor

Comment: You provided only the js. Please provide a complete html (or a working jsfiddle/codepen)

Comment: @Dekel, cannot provide entire html, but it's very basic use of ckEditor as you can see from example

Comment: Every basic use can be wrong with some irrelevant js code that breaks it :)

Comment: It might be a problem with angular and not ckeditor

Comment: As I mentioned in question, code works fine in other browsers, so I'm assuming that IE8 is causing issue

Comment: The code in this jsfiddle works great on ie8: https://jsfiddle.net/pu991b6e/ **the jsfiddle itself will not work** because jsfiddle doesn't support IE8, but the code inside will.

Comment: Also - note that jQuery 2 doesn't support IE8 and Angular 1.3 also doesn't support IE8. So if you need IE8 support you must use jquery 1 & angular 1.2.

Comment: I agree that code works, on my page ckEditor is correctly loaded and data is displayed and updated without errors. Problem is that inside console log an "Permission denied" error is shown and it points to 54th line of ckeditor.js file which is referenced through cdn link. I'm using Angular 1.2.0 and jQuery 1.11.3 - sorry for not mentionig that earlier.

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.5.5, CKEditor 4.6.2 and I get this issue on IE11